# Git Diff to Perforce?

Tags: git, perforce

We have a Perforce repository and we later switched to Git. Still we have a release branch that is in perforce and now, I need to apply some of the git commits to the perforce branch.

According to what I have read, it seems this can be done by doing a git diff, creating a patch and then applying to the perforce code base. But, I have seen any concrete example. Could anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can form a patch from git history with a simple `git diff <point1>..<point2> > the_diff.patch` and then apply that patch to your working tree using `patch -p1 <the_diff.patch` and commit the changes to perforce.

Also you could form a sequence of git commits as separate patch files using `git format-patch <point1>..<point2>` and apply them sequentally if you wish.

There's [git-p4](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4) tool to import/export commits from/to git and perforce repositories, but I haven't use it so far.

For Windows users who do not have git installed (well, I do suggest to install it anyway :-)), one can use [Patch for Windows](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm) or install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) bundle which contains the utility.

Alternatively one can try to apply patches using their favorite IDE.

Comment: Is the `patch` command a unix dependency? If so, any suggestions for other platforms?

Comment: patch is a rather portable tool. What platform do you use?

Comment: I'm really just trying to help [How to send changes from a git commit to a non-git user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76467697/how-to-send-changes-from-a-git-commit-to-a-non-git-user) which got closed as a duplicate of this question. They appear to be on Windows.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Feel free to make necessary corrections too because I'm not a Windows user with a fresh hands-on experience.