# How to send changes from a git commit to a non-git user?

Tags: git, diff, perforce

I develop a project in Git, but some users copy the source into their own Perforce repository. Often I want to send them a change from some commit, like a bug fix from a newer version of the project. I can give them a .patch, but they don't have git apply. Is there an easy tool for applying .patch files on Windows? Or some other format I could convert the diff into? Or any other easy way for them to get the commit from GitHub into their Perforce?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the linked question depends on a unix `patch` command and won't be useful to this Windows questioner. But some of the answers to [How do I apply a diff patch on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517257/how-do-i-apply-a-diff-patch-on-windows) might be helpful.